# What is a right way making different saga side effects based on certain condition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-saga

I have 2 pages(routes) as part of SPA, let's say page 1 and page 2.
I have an action 'MY_ACTION', that is dispatched by both pages.

I need to trigger side-effect for 'MY_ACTION', but only to be executed for page 2.

Any idea how could that be done with redux-saga? I have a thought, that I can do the following:

```
export function* rootSaga(){ 
    yield takeEvery(action => action.type === 'MY_ACTION' && {routeId === 'page2'}, () => console.log('MY_ACTION')); 
}
```

**Note**, that  {routeId === 'page2'} is a pseudocode.

Will that be a right way to do such filtering on actions? 
Or maybe someone could suggest another architectural approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would have the pages include the additional information in the action object, and then let your saga filter based on that additional field.

Comment: i have react-router-redux integrated, so have an access to routing info anytime. just worry about extra load on system during actions filtering...